# How to display only the menu items and not the parent menu?

Tags: entities, routes

I am trying to build on the footer a set of 3 menu links: About us, Terms of Use, Contact.

The problem is that I want to have only these 3 links as menus and I do not want their parent menu to be displayed. Can anyone help me on this?

When I do it, I can display the 3 links, but also their parent menu is shown. 
I want to display only the submenu items:

- MenuItem1

  - submenuitem1
  - submenuitem2
  - submenuitem3

Is that possible? Can The Panel module do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Menu block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module is the way to go.

- Install the module
- Go to your blocks page
- Click on "Add new menu block"
- Select your menu and the level you want it to show
- Add that block to your footer region and you're set

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Menu block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, or print sub-menus or any level menus.

```
echo theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
  'links' => menu_navigation_links('main-menu', '1'),
  'attributes' => array(
  'id' => 'main-menu-level-2-id',
  'class' => array('links')
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For three menu items, I wouldn't install another module. I'd create a new custom menu and add the items manually. The custom menu can then be set to be displayed in the footer by using the blocks admin page.